# How to take care of the hurting shoulder joint?

Tags: bodybuilding, strength-training, injury, injury-prevention

I think I've hurt my right shoulder. I don't know what caused it but it is painful. I noticed it today while taking bath. I clean my back by applying soap with my hands somewhat like this:

[image]

I when I do whats shown above, with my left hand, my fingers reach my right spine of scapula. But when I try to do the same with my right hand, it hurts in the shoulder joint. This is the only motion (orientation of right hand) in which its hurting. That is the reason why it went unnoticed in the gym. I don't do any such motion in the gym.

What to do? What should I avoid in the gym? How to cure it?

Answer (score 2):

Shoulder injuries are one of the most difficult injuries to overcome.  They are right up there with knee and neck injuries.

My recommendation to you is to stop all weight exercises that involve the shoulder immediately.  Allow the joint to rest properly for at least a month before returning to using weight and begin slowly.  Low weight, low reps.  In the meantime, you can do some light swimming and stretching to allow oxigen and nutrients to nurture the muscles and joints and help it heal.

If after that month of rest you still have issues and show no progress, I suggest visiting a Physical Therapist that specializes in shoulders.

The last thing you want is to incurr a serious shoulder injury that will require surgery and at least a year of recovery.